# Values of Enum to Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, enums

I have an enum class in javascript like this:

```
var Produce= {
     Apple: 1,
     Banana: 2,
     Tomato: 3,
     Orange: 4
    }
```

I can create an array of these items which I use in a mongo db query with the following:

```
var fruit = [Produce.Apple,Produce.Banana, Produce.Orange];
```

This works fine and returns the true values like this:

```
fruit[0] = 2(Apple), fruit[1] = 2(Banana), fruit[2] = 4(Orange)
```

Everything is fine to that point.  However, I also need to create an array of items that are NOT fruit.  In reality the enumeration has over 50 values and can grow.  Which means I need to make and array of values NOT to be included with code.

I've tried the following and nothing works.

The problem is that the produce array does not recognize length or count

```
var excludedProduce = [];  

for(var i = 0; i < produce.length ; i++){
     if( fruit.indexOf(produce[0]) == -1) //add
         excludedProduce .push(produce[0]);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like you're trying to programming in JS like you're used in other languages... I'm not sure if it's a good approach, and may bite you... Why don't you create an array of products like `var products = [{ name: 'Banana', isFruit: true  }, { name: 'Car', isFruit: false}]`?

Comment: LOL:  I have programmed in other languages more...unfortunately I don't have much say over how this gets done.  The problem is that there could be any number of 'vegetables' added that I don't want to use.  In mongo query, you have to not just say what values you want to find ($in) but you also have to state what values you don't want ($nin).

Comment: Is this question really related to MongoDB? (There's a tag for that)

Comment: Yes, on the MongoDB.  If you know a way to return only values in the $in statement.  A collection with nested collections will return all nested values if any of those match the $in parameter.  The only way to limit is to say $in (parameters) AND $nin (parameters).  If there is another way, please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
var fruit = [Produce.Apple,Produce.Banana, Produce.Orange];
var excludedProduce = [];
for (var p in Produce) {
    if (Produce.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
        if (fruit.indexOf(Produce[p]) === -1) {
            excludedProduce.push(Produce[p]);
        }
    }
}
```

Explanation:

- Loop through the keys in Produce using in
- Make sure they aren't prototype properties before using them
- Check if the value isn't in the fruits array
- If it isn't push the value into the excludedProduce array

In regards to your code there any several issues mainly due to you treating the object like it's an array and expecting it to act like one. I'd recommend reading a book like [Javascript the Good Parts](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517748.do) if you'd like to learn more about the language or using a framework like [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) to abstract some of this away and allow you to easily loop through objects and perform other cool helper operations on them.